# Возможно ли при hover на элементе изменить свойства другого элемента?

Tags: css3, javascript

CSS3. Возможно ли при hover на элементе изменить свойства другого элемента, а не того, на который навели?

Пример:

```
<div>
  <img/>
</div>
```

Как при `div:hover { }` изменить свойства не `div`, а `img`?

Answer (score 4):

Да. Селектор:

```
div:hover img{
    border: 1px black;
}
```

Comment: Верно, и js не нужен... :)

Comment: Дык, давайте **thumbs up**! :)

Answer (score 0):

Через js.

Пример:

```
function changestyle()
{
document.getElementById('myid').style.border="1px"
}
<div onmouseover="changestyle()">text</div>;
<img srd="/img/img.jpg" id="myid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно задать размеры (`width` и `height`) для  `div`, а саму картинку прописать в стилях в качестве `background`.
Тогда, в стилях прописать еще один стиль - для `div:hover` и изменить картинку.